# BorderLayout, GridLayout, GridBagLayout? Which should I use?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to create this basic GUI, but cannot get my panels to setup correctly.(Numbers are pixel sizes)

[image: GUI]

I've tried using this tutorial as a reference (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl3klve_rmQ) but, mine never works the same.

My code declares variables in the top of the class, then creates a constructor which add the components (panels, buttons, etc), then it calls the constructor in the main method.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

public class FinalProject extends JPanel 
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static JPanel nav;
static JPanel queue;
static JPanel menu;

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

public FinalProject() 
{

    nav = new JPanel();
    nav.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    nav.setBackground(Color.RED);
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(nav, gbc);

    queue = new JPanel();
    queue.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    queue.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(queue, gbc);

    menu = new JPanel();
    menu.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    menu.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(menu, gbc);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    FinalProject p = new FinalProject();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.add(nav);
    f.add(queue);
    f.add(menu);

    f.setTitle("Subway");
    f.setSize(800, 500);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.add(p);
}
```

}

How should I go about getting this layout right? Panels in Panels, Panels independent of each other, etc.?

Comment: My suggestion: mostly what you need is a BorderLayout, but having said that, my main suggestion is for you to try it out, and then show code if you're still having problems. Otherwise, it will be hard for us to guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I've posted my code :)

Comment: You only add one button...try adding the others, one at NORTH and one at the center.

Comment: .................. better attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, don't use a GridBagLayout for this as you'll be adding more complexity than is actually needed. Myself, I try to avoid using this layout and all its potential pitfalls as much as possible, and usually you can get all you need by nesting JPanels, each using its own more simple layout. For instance here, all you need is a BorderLayout:

- Place the top JPanel in the BorderLayout.NORTH position
- Place the left JPanel in the BorderLayout.WEST position
- Place the center JPanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.

That's it.

Again, please check out the Swing and the layout manager tutorials as the information is well presented there.

---

**Edit**
Note that nothing shows up on your JFrame because you're not adding your JPanel to the JFrame!

---

**Edit 2**
For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleLayout {
   private static final Color GREEN = new Color(200, 255, 200);
   private static final Color BLUE = new Color(200, 200, 255);

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleLayout");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // note that a JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorPanel(Color.pink, 800, 80), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorPanel(GREEN, 300, 420), BorderLayout.WEST);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorPanel(BLUE, 500, 420), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final float FONT_POINTS = 24f;
   private int prefW;
   private int prefH;

   public ColorPanel(Color color, int prefW, int prefH) {
      setBackground(color);
      this.prefW = prefW;
      this.prefH = prefH;

      // GBL can be useful for simply centering components
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
      String text = String.format("%d x %d", prefW, prefH);
      JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(FONT_POINTS));
      label.setForeground(Color.gray);
      add(label);
   }



   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }
}
```

---

This displays as:

[image]

Comment: I added them but now everything is blue. I have tried this borderlayout but with gridbag I have things showing up at least.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Very clever way to get the label name as well.

Answer (score 2):

`GridLayout` I've never actually used but I'm not sure if it can do this.

`BorderLayout` can do this and is simpler to use than `GridBagLayout`.

`GridBagLayout` can do this.

In general `GridBagLayout` is one of the most flexible `LayoutManager`s and is well worth learning so I'd recommend using it here to get used to it on a simple case before you need it anyway for something more complex.

If you are familiar with HTML then think of `GridBagLayout` as working like HTML tables.

Very quickly - create the three panels and set the sizes/borders/whatever you need in them.

Add one in cell 0,0 with a colspan of 2.
Add one in cell 1,0
Add one in cell 1,1

After that you are done although you will probably want to specify resize/anchor/etc behaviour.

Comment: I'm kinda of familiar with GridBagLayout and Constraints. Any idea of how I could get 3 panels align the way i'd like with the proper constraints? css does `float: left`, is there something similar in gridbag?

Comment: I'll add a very quick summary.

Comment: I've posted an update above. Nothing shows up on my frame and I think I'm kind of close with my gridx and gridy setup.

Comment: @MikeMilla: You're not adding your JPanel to the JFrame.

Comment: I added them with gridbag and it's still messed up... Only seeing blue.